# Detect & floodfill ROI using OpenCV

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv, emgucv, imaging

i have a document image (b/w, 300dpi) containing newspaper like formated text (title, paragraph columns etc).
- How can i detect paragraphs columns to floodfill them with Black Color?
- How can i get distance with of floodfill textcolumns?

Is this possible using OpenCV or EmguCV/C# ?

See this link http://goo.gl/6djHt (no Spam its a shortlink) of what i mean.

Thanks in advance for any hints and code-snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You could try counting the number of black pixels in each column of the image. This will give you an array that looks like this (all the numbers are made up):

`0 0 0 987 935 967 923 975 954 932 944 0 0 0 923 965 987 933 965 976 922 0 0 0`

So basically you have some large numbers, and some zeros. The large numbers indicate columns that contain text. The zeros indicate columns that don't contain anything. If there is noise in the image, you may not get zeros, but you may get small numbers and you can handle them.

You can split the image using the array above and get the columns. You may then use a similar technique to find the rows of text (by summing up black pixels in the rows of the image). You can also use this technique to measure the distance between paragraphs.

This method can fail when the lines of text are not horizontal. Also, this may fail when you have to analyze an entire page of a newspaper and the layout is complicated. But this is a good technique to try if you need to process images like the one in your link.

Comment: thank you for answering, this could be an approach but it must be a way to accomplish in OpenCV especially detecting paragraph outlines and floodfill them with black color...

Comment: i think the above method is excellent and would be a lot efficient as opposed to floodfilling them. Once you detect the corners and edge points, you can its convex hull or the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score -1):

Try cvDetectParagraph().

In all seriousness, the other poster already answered your question and you just seem to want someone to do the job for you. If you could get away of being so lazy, software programming wouldn't be a profession.

Comment: hello wisecracker,i am sorry i dont want to snub somebody but i was going to find a way using opencv. i am not an expert in opencv so my intention was to know if it exists any method (or combination of methods) of opencv and not a ready to use solution. OK!